# Create a dictionary from a string by separating the string using a word

Tags: c#, dictionary

Str = 7 X 4 @ 70Hz LUVYG

I want to split the string  with Hz

Key: 7 X 4 @ 70Hz
Value: LUVYG

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: After answering your question, I would encourage you in the future to spend as much time asking as I have just spent answering. Take a good read of the [help] section, play by the rules and your experience on stackoverflow will be much more positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the regular expression

```
^              - start of string
 (.*)          - zero or more characters (Groups[1])
     \s        - whitespace
       (\S*)   - zero or more non-whitespace characters (Groups[2])
            $  - end of string
```

it is possible to split a string into 2 groups, using the last whitespace in the string as the delimiter.

Using this regular expression, you can use LINQ to process a collection of strings into a dictionary:

```
var unprocessed = new[] { "7 X 4 @ 70Hz LUVYG" };
var dict =
    unprocessed
        .Select(w => Regex.Match(w, @"^(.*)\s(\S*)$"))
        .Where(m => m.Success)
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```